# react router 4 404 path in case of dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404

I am working with the latest React Router ( 4 ) version. I have a dynamic config for my routes, just like it described in the tutorial. It works fine but when I has tried to add the 404 path (just like in the tutorial) it starts to show this 404 page right before loading any normal component with the correct path.

*In case of nonexistent path the 404 route works correctly.*

*In case of move to an allowed route config)*

First - 404 component showed ( I don't know why )
Second - Normal component showed and the 404 component has disappeared.

Does anyone have any information how this issue can be fixed? Thanks for any information!

Here is my route config.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Config } from "shared/services";
import lazyRoute from "./lazyRoute";

const navScheme = Config.navigationScheme;

const COMPLEX_ROUTES = route => {
    console.log("routesss ->> ", route);
    return (
        <Switch >
            <Route path={route.path} exact={!!route.exact} render={props => (
                // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
                <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
            )}/>
        </Switch>
    );
};


const generateRoutes = routes => routes.map((route, i) => (
    <COMPLEX_ROUTES key={i} {...route}/>
));

const PLATFORM_CHILD_ROUTES = [
    {
        path : navScheme.platform,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/home/Home.module")),
        exact : true
    }
];

const ROUTES = [
    {
        path : navScheme.root,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/landing-page/LandingPage.module")),
        exact : true
    },

    {
        path : navScheme.platform,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../components/Platform")),
        routes : PLATFORM_CHILD_ROUTES
    },

    {
        path : "*",
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/errors/Error404.module"))
    },

];


export { generateRoutes, ROUTES };
```

Comment: how do you do this lazyRoute() ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this issue.

In the react-router documentation we can see that:

`A <Switch> renders the first child <Route> that matches. A <Route> with no path always matches.`

It's mean that we should add the Switch component into our route scheme to show only THE FIRST one matched component. I had the Switch but in a wrong place. It should wrap the generated routes but in my case it was "inner wrapper".

After these changes my config looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Config } from "shared/services";
import lazyRoute from "./lazyRoute";

const navScheme = Config.navigationScheme;

const COMPLEX_ROUTES = route => {
    return (
            <Route path={route.path} exact={!!route.exact} render={props => (
                // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
                <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
            )}/>
    );
};


const generateRoutes = routes => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            {
                routes.map((route, i) => (
                    <COMPLEX_ROUTES key={i} {...route}/>
                ))
            }
        </Switch>
    );
};

const PLATFORM_CHILD_ROUTES = [
    {
        path : navScheme.platform,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/home/Home.module")),
        exact : true
    }
];

const ROUTES = [
    {
        path : navScheme.root,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/landing-page/LandingPage.module")),
        exact : true
    },

    {
        path : navScheme.platform,
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../components/Platform")),
        routes : PLATFORM_CHILD_ROUTES
    },

    {
        path : "*",
        component : lazyRoute(() => import("../../modules/errors/Error404.module"))
    },

];


export { generateRoutes, ROUTES };
```

Hope it helps someone. 
Best regards. Velidan